# Laravel Forge, Git, Bitbucket and deployment to Digitalocean

Tags: git, bitbucket, laravel-5, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I've deployed my site to DigitalOcean droplet. Now I made some changes locally, pushed to my Bitbucket repo and when I log on to Forge and click on Deploy I get the following message:

```
From bitbucket.org:myUsername/myBucket
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

So if I get this right he won't update `MyController` on my droplet because it will get overwritten? Isn't that the point of deploy?

Obviously I'm getting something wrong here so any help is appreciated.

This is my deployment script:

```
cd /home/forge/mysite.com
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force --seed
php artisan migrate --path=vendor/mpociot/versionable/src/migrations
```

Comment: Solved by SSH into server and running `git stash` then `git pull`. I presume the `git stash` should be added to deployment script but the thing is I don't see any reason to stash old files on live server. Waiting for suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Looks like you've edited the `app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php` on the server. Now in the commit you're trying to pull the same file has been changed. Therefore it's now giving the message that the changes you made will be overwritten. In the future you can check it by by running `git status` and `git diff` on your server and then decide whether you really need those changes or not.